# Javascript: Convert Object to String Recursively (including child objects and arrays) as if there were quotes around it (unlike JSON.stringify)

Tags: javascript, string, object

**This question has been resolved.**

Based on the answer from **karuzo**, I made a finalized version:

```
$['to'] = function ($a)
{
    $u = JSON.stringify(this); $w = this.typeof(); $x = $a.typeof();

    if ($x == 'Array')
    {
        if ($w == 'Object')
        {
            $y = []; this.keys().for(($l, $m, $n) =>
            {
                $y[$m] = [$l, this[$l]];
            });

            return $y;
        }

        else if ($w == 'Array')
        {
            return [].slice.call(this);
        }

        else if ($w == 'String')
        {
            return [this];
        };
    }

    else if ($x == 'Object')
    {
        if ($w == 'Object')
        {
            return this.to("").from({});
        }

        else if ($w == 'Array')
        {
            $y = {}; this.for(($l, $m, $n) =>
            {
                $l != {}._ ? $y[$m] = $l : null;
            });

            return $y;
        }

        else if ($w == 'String')
        {
            return {value: this};
        }
    }

    else if ($x == 'String')
    {
        if ($w == 'Object')
        {
            return JSON.stringify(this).replace(/\"([^(\")"]+)\":/g, '$1:');
        }

        else if ($w == 'Array')
        {
            return $u;
        }

        else if ($w == 'String' | $w == 'Number')
        {
            return this.toString();
        };
    }

    else
    {
        return this;
    };
}
```

This version is included directly in paxiom.js, the file which the code resides.
Some of the functions used in the above code are in the library. I know this tends to get some viewers, so when the library's version #1 is finished, it will be available at https://hbms.github.io/-/paxiom.js

Comment: If there are other possible duplicate questions, please explain why they did not help, so that we know what you're having trouble with.

Comment: What exactly is the question? I.e. can you give some testcases where JSON.stringify or the other solutions you tried fail to work?

Comment: Please show your desired input & output.

Comment: @4castle added it

Comment: So why `JSON.stringify` doesn't work for you? Are you getting any errors? `JSON.stringify` sounds like it is what you want. It will recursively serialize a dictionary, array, or any other primitive value into a string. For example, if I pass in you're input object, it will produce `"{"a":"x","b":["y"],"c":{"d":["z"]},"e":[{"f":"g"}]}"` as a string. `JSON.parse` on the stringified representation will give you you're input object again.

Comment: Based on your desired output, I don't see why `JSON.stringify` doesn't "perfectly represent the object input". Objects created with object-literal notation don't have any inherent formatting, so you can't get the output to always look like your source code. I also don't see the value in making it look like your source code.

Comment: @NormanBreau it doesn't work because it returns the object keys with quotes around them `'{"key": "value"}'` which is not what I need `'{key: "value"}'`

Comment: @4castle I need to be able to put the string through eval function. I'm also making it for a library, so others can use it. It's also to show my friends I can do it.

Comment: @hbms Why do you need to use the `eval` function? Most people regard that function as a big security hole. Regardless, `eval` can read the output from `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @4castle I know it seems dumb but I'd really like for this to work. Honestly I think a perfect-representation string of an object could be very useful in certain situations. Also, it would be an amazing accomplishment to make it work.

Comment: Is this a code golf or something? What's with all the one letter variable names?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli It's for a library, you wont see the code xD

Comment: I just did, because you posted it online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
var obj = {a: "x", b: ["y"], c: {d: ["z"]}, e: [{f: "g"}]};

var objStr = JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/\"([^(\")"]+)\":/g,"$1:");

console.log(objStr);
```

Output:

`{a:"x",b:["y"],c:{d:["z"]},e:[{f:"g"}]}`

And you can `eval()` the resulting string:

`var obj = eval(objStr)`